# Facebook sharer link displaying og meta tags

Tags: angularjs, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I´m trying to integrate Facebook share button (sharer link) in my AngularJs webapp.

I have this link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=/{{locationService.getLangKey()}}/blog/{{'POST_URL_' + post.title | translate}}" class="popup" target="_blank">
```

So, when I click on it the share windows is opened. However, it is only displaying a text field with the url and a share button. I would also like to include an image, title and description. I´m new to this share functionality, but I have read Facebook get this information form Open Graph meta tags.

So, I have included them (just with some testing info):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Ridiculously Responsive Social Sharing Buttons" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://kurtnoble.com/labs/rrssb/index.html" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://kurtnoble.com/labs/rrssb/media/facebook-share.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="No one wants to create social buttons over and over again. RRSSB is a super flexible system that works in any container. SASS-powered, retina ready, svg images, tiny file size and auto-magical resizing. A KNI Labs freebie."/>
```

However, I don´t see it in my share window.

Note: I have read this functionality could have problems with AngularJS application, because FB is not able to read the javascript code inside curling braces (More or less same problem that Google crawler). But before face that problem, just for testing purposes, I´m not using dynamic content but statical.

Answer (score 0):

The [Facebook URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) is a useful tool for such cases. This will help you find any issues with the open graph meta tags and fix them.

Keep in mind that when a URL is shared in Facebook, the result is cached and even if the page has changed, Facebook shows the cached results.

The Facebook debugger also invalidates any cache for the provided URL.

Comment: I have checked the results in Facebook URL Debugger. They look fine. I attach my testing url /to be shared). http://www.test.yanpy.com/es/blog/rutas-para-navegar-por-ibiza-y-formentera

Comment: Facebook will get all meta information from `http://kurtnoble.com/labs/rrssb/index.html`, because you have specified that as the `og:url` value.

Comment: All information loaded correctly in Facebook when I tried it. I am guessing that it is a caching issue.

Comment: I have changed the og:url to my url. But I think the problem was a meta author I had and Facebook was complaining about it. I have removed it and looks like it´s working.